# Can't create directory on hadoop file system

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I installed `hadoop 2.7.1` from root in `/usr/local`

now i want to give access to multiple users

when i executed the following command

```
 hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
```

from hadoop user i got the error

```
mkdir: Permission denied: user=hadoop, access=WRITE, inode="/user":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

how to resolve this problem . please help me in this

Thanks 
suchetan

Answer (score 0):

hdfs user is the admin user for the HDFS. Change to hdfs user and give the necessary permissions to the user you want(hadoop)

or

you can disable the `dfs.permissions.enabled` in the hdfs_site.xml and restart. After that you can create a folder.

Comment: i did it. problem solved. but my doubt is i am planning to provide multi user setup. so i want to run multiple applications from multiple users . there should be isolation between each users data. But here any user can access another user data. i dont want to encourage it